# Script executes after inspecting window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks, jquery-waypoints

What I'm doing here is changing the opacity of the header and adding a searchbar when it reaches a waypoint (A bigger searchbar). ***It works, the problem here is that the change is only applied after I inspect the window and change between screen sizes.***

Even a simple console log only happens after inspecting the windows

**CoffeeScript**

```
$(document).ready ->  #The indentation is correct
  if $('#hero-image').length > 0
    $searchBarMin = $('header #search-bar-group')
    $searchaBar = $('#big-search-bar')
    $header = $('header')
    $nearYou = $('#near-you')
    $searchBarMin.hide()
    $header.css({background: "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0.3))", position: "absolute" })
    waypoint = new Waypoint({
        element: $('#near-you'),
        handler: (direction)->
            console.log '!///////////////////'
            if (direction == "down")
                $searchBarMin.show()
                $header.css({background: "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,1))" })
            else
                $searchBarMin.hide()
                $header.css({background: "linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0.3))" })   
    })
```

**Header html**

```
<header id="header-logged-in" class="expanded row">
<div id="logo-container" class="small-6 small-push-3 medium-3 medium-push-0 large-2 columns">
    <%= link_to root_path do %>
        <%= image_tag("TA_logo01.png") %>
    <% end %>
</div>
<div class="small-12 medium-3 large-1 text-center columns">
    <h6><i><%= link_to "What is TattooAdvisor", what_is_tattoo_advisor_path %></i></h6>
</div>
<div id="search-bar-container" class="large-5 show-for-large columns" action='/search' >
    <%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
        <div id="search-bar-group" class="row collapse">
            <div class="small-9 medium-6 medium-push-2 large-7 large-push-3 columns">
                <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], data: {autocomplete_source: Artist.order(:name).map{ |u| {id: u.slug, reference: u.reference,state: u.state, label: u.name, image: u.avatar.url(:thumb) }} + Parlour.order(:name).map{ |u| {id: u.slug, label: u.name, reference: u.reference, state: u.state, image: u.avatar.url(:thumb) }}}, class: "name_autocomplete_search input-group-field", placeholder: "Search for parlours and artists"%> 
            </div>  
            <div id="search-button" class="small-2 small-pull-1 medium-pull-2 large-pull-1 columns">
                <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "button" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
<div id="log-in-div" class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 menu-centered columns">
    <ul class="menu dropdown large-pull-1" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li>
            <div class="small-6 medium-6 large-push-2 columns">
                <%= avatar_profile_link current_user, "thumb", class: 'logged-in-picture' %>
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 small-pull-1 medium-6 large-pull-0 columns">
                    <h4><%= current_user.display_name %></h4>
                </div>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="upper-pad">
                    <%= link_to "Profile", profile_standard_path %>
                </li>
                <% if current_user.has_role? :artist %>
                    <li class="upper-pad">
                        <%= link_to "Artist Profile", profile_artist_path %>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
                <% if  current_user.has_role? :parlour %>
                    <li class="upper-pad">
                        <%= link_to "Parlour Profile", profile_parlour_path %>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
                <li id="premium-drop-down-li">
                    <b><%= link_to "Upgrade Account", subscription_path %></b>
                </li>
                <li class="upper-pad">
                    <%= link_to "Invite", new_invite_path %>
                </li>
                <li class="upper-pad">
                    <%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="small-5 small-pull-1 medium-1 medium-pull-3 large-pull-5 columns">
        <%= link_to "Review", new_review_path, class:'button' %>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="search-bar-container" class="small-12 columns hide-for-large" action='/search' >
    <%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
        <div id="search-bar-group" class="row collapse">
            <div id="search-bar" class="small-9 medium-6 medium-push-2 columns">
                <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], data: {autocomplete_source: Artist.order(:name).map{ |u| {id: u.slug, reference: u.reference,state: u.state, label: u.name, image: u.avatar.url(:thumb) }} + Parlour.order(:name).map{ |u| {id: u.slug, label: u.name, reference: u.reference, state: u.state, image: u.avatar.url(:thumb) }}}, class: "name_autocomplete_search input-group-field", placeholder: "Search for parlours and artists"%> 
            </div>  
            <div id="search-button" class="small-2 small-pull-1 medium-pull-2 columns">
                <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "button" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**HomePage**

```
<div class="row full-width">
<div class="small-12 columns">
    <div id="hero-image" class="row expanded">
        <div id="front-search-box" class="small-12 medium-6 medium-centered large-4 columns  collapse">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h3><i>Tattoos are art<br>
                    Art is subjective</i></h3>
                    <h5>Find the right artist for your tattoo</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <%= render 'search_box' %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<%= render partial: 'near_you' %>
```

**SearchBox Partial**

```
<div class="row collapse">
<div class="small-11 menu" action='/search' >
    <%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
        <div id="big-search-bar" class="row collapse">
            <div class="small-10 column">
                <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], data: {autocomplete_source: Artist.order(:name).map{ |u| {id: u.slug, reference: u.reference,state: u.state, label: u.name, image: u.avatar.url(:thumb) }} + Parlour.order(:name).map{ |u| {id: u.slug, label: u.name, reference: u.reference, state: u.state, image: u.avatar.url(:thumb) }}}, class: "name_autocomplete_search input-group-field", placeholder: "Search for parlours and artists"%> 
            </div>  
            <div id="search-button" class="small-2 column">
                <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "button" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Rails version: 4.2.6.

Turbolinks: 5.0.1

Foundation 6.3.

Waypoints (Latests version, installed with bower)

Comment: Is that the real indentation in your CoffeeScript? Are you using anything to make `$(document).ready` work with Turbolinks?

Comment: This was just me trying something else, but i have also tried doing it with turbolinks:load

Comment: The question about CoffeeScript indentation is a very important one. As written you get `$(document).ready(function() {});` then all your code (outside the document ready event listener). The turbolinks consideration is also important, but check the JS that the browser has loaded to see if it is what you expect. Also use js2.coffee to make sure you are generating what you expect.

Comment: indeed the js2.coffee seems to be showing the right JavaScript, have you tried to use `$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->`?

Comment: Yes I have also tried with turbolinks:load...

Comment: Can you paste in the `<head>` of your html, and have you tried disabling turbolinks to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Where is this `$('#near-you')` element that's being targeted?

Comment: If you can make the entire generated HTML, JS, and CSS available as a jsfiddle or on codepen, that will make investigating much more fruitful. There are lots of things that could contribute, from JS load order dependency to CSS selector specificity to really anything. Since this is a front end issue, the server side rendering shouldn't effect anything - just the resulting HTML and JS matter.

Comment: It's complicated to upload a fiddle that displays properly, but I just found out that the code also updates when I resize the window

Comment: What about deploying to heroku and providing a link?

Comment: This is the link
https://staging.tattooadvisor.com/

You must log in to activate the full functionality use this acount

Esteban-0418@hotmail.com
tattooadvisor123

Comment: Just scroll past the searchbar and change the screen size to see thescrip get executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a css issue clashing with the way waypoint.js works.

First thing you need to change is remove the property `height: 100%` on `body`, but keep it on `html`.

```
html{
  height: 100%; # not on body, just html
  ...
}
```

Then, your `header` position attribute needs to be `fixed` and not `absolute`.

```
header{
  position: fixed; # not absolute
  ...
}
```

If you do all this it should work.

Comment: Could you please explain why it has to be position fixed and not absolute?